# how can I change managed metadata type to "One line text" type

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I have lists which inherits content types from their parent site. These content types are versioned an they have managed metadata site columns. I wonder to know what is the best approach to change the content types managed metadata fields to simple line of text type.